# *** buffer overflow detected *** /usr/bin/expect terminated

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

I am running a tcl script which invokes ssh sessions to multiple servers and keeps it alive for further operations. But I am getting this below error after it does ssh to 1023 Servers.

[image]

I have set soft and hard limits to larger value, but still no luck.

Below is the Server **limit.conf** details and multiple options that I have tried.

**Ulimit -a**

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited

scheduling priority             (-e) 0

file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited

pending signals                 (-i) 31189

max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64

max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

**open files                      (-n) 65536**

pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8

POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 268435456

real-time priority              (-r) 0

stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192

cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

max user processes              (-u) 65536

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

file locks                      (-x) unlimited

**cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max**

65536

**cat /etc/pam.d/login** also contains ==> **session    required     /lib64/security/pam_limits.so**

Tried multiple approach including the links https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19623-01/820-6168/file-descriptor-requirements.html

Please help.

Comment: Is there any tcl code here?

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty yes

Comment: I still don't see an Tcl code.  Maybe because you haven't used code formatting?

Comment: You need to show us the code you're trying to run (up to the spawn, and *not* including any passwords or other credentials!) You also need to say which version of the OS, Tcl and Expect are in use. Which exact version of Tcl 8.5 are we talking here? (Is this something where a simple upgrade to the current version will fix it? If so, no other fix will ever be offered.)

Comment: You're creating hundreds of ssh sessions: do they all need to be open simultaneously or are they running in series? Do you call `wait` and `close` on the spawned sessions?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're going over the limit of what the Tcl event notifier can handle, as that is based (on Unix) on the `select()` system call which has a limit on the maximum FD number supported. In particular, it is limited by the size of a structure on the stack that is set at compile time to (usually) 1024 entries, and Tcl reserves a few file descriptors for other things (e.g., standard in and out). This is a limit on the maximum value of the FD, and not just on the maximum number of open descriptors. Going over the maximum does a buffer overrun in the stack (in a hard-to-control way) and trips the memory protection code that produces the error you saw. (If using Tcl 8.5 or 8.6, you might want to `ulimit -n 1024` to convert a nasty crash into a much nicer one.)

We have fixed this in 8.7 by switching to other system calls that don't have the limitation (8.7a3 was released last month) and despite it being alpha it should be stable enough for this sort of thing. But if that won't do, you have to split your workload of ssh sessions up between multiple processes; perhaps 512 each will work or maybe half that if that still hits an API limit? Having two or four manager processes instead of one (you can easily have a master process controlling the others over pipes) isn't a great increase in load on the average modern computer. Or even the average one from a decade or two ago.

Another approach that might be viable in some cases is to run screen inside those ssh sessions so that you can disconnect from them (without losing what was going on) and so keep the number of simultaneous in-use FDs down. That isn't a universal solution.

Comment: The details of what was changed to fix this are in https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/458.md